# How to concat a variable to the name of another with web languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, concatenation

I lack some basics in these languages so it might be an easy question.

I receive an json encoded array of object from an ajax call. At the begining of it, I add some elements I need :

```
array_unshift($data, array('nbr' => 6,'Col1' => 'Company name', 
'Col2' => 'Email','Col3' => 'Adress','Col4' => 'City',
'Col5' => 'Code','Col6' => 'Country));
```

In the `success:function(msg)` of the ajax I want to iterate through these elements to make them the headers of a table :

```
var qtt=msg[0].nbr;
$foo='<table>';
for (var i = 1; i<qtt; i++) {
    $foo=$foo+'<th>'+msg[i].Col+i+'</th>';
}
$foo=$foo+'</table>;
```

I want to access the i'th element of msg and I know it is named 'Col'+i. To me, it looks simple and difficult at the same time.

I just don't know how to do this, no idea. Any help is welcome.

**Edit :**
With firebug I could retreive the answer of the ajax call. If it can help you here it is (the element are in french but it is exactly what I was talking about previously) :

```
[{"nbr":6,"Col1":"Nom soci\u00e9t\u00e9","Col2":"Email","Col3":"Adresse",
"Col4":"Ville","Col5":"Code postal","Col6":"Pays"},
{"Soc_Nom":"foo1","Soc_Email":"bar1","Soc_Adresse":"foobar1", "Vil_Nom":
"Foofoo1","Vil_Code_Postal":"1000","Pys_Nom":"Belgique"},{"Soc_Nom":
"Foo2","Soc_Email":"Bar2","Soc_Adresse":"foobar2","Vil_Nom":"Foofoo2",
"Vil_Code_Postal":"2000","Pys_Nom":"Belgique"}]
```

**Ansewer :**
No need to iterate through msg[] since all the info I wanted to access was in msg[0].

Using msg[0]['Col'+i] works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to access a property name dynamically, you can use an indexer with the property name as a string:

```
$foo=$foo+'<th>'+msg[i].Col+i+'</th>';
```

becomes

```
$foo=$foo+'<th>'+msg[i]['Col' + i]+'</th>';
```

`msg[i].Col + i` (your original code) is looking for a property named `Col` and trying to add the value of `Col` to the value of `i`.

The second example is building a dynamic property name `'Col' + i`, and using brackets to access a property of that name on the `msg[i]` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: I don't get any error but instead of Company name, Email or anything else it returns Undifined. I took some time to answer because I was trying to fix this but I couldn't find the origin of this issue. Any idea ?

Comment: Add : I checked that the msg contained the right data with two $.each and an alert(). Nothing wrong on that side.

Comment: @AlexandreRivara  can you provide the object structure when you are in the loop?  e.g., set a break point, and open the console window (F12 in Chrome on windows), then type `msg[i]`.  That should show you the object structure and allow you to expand or collapse properties.

Comment: Sorry I tried to but the file that contain the loop isn't listed in the source file available to the debugger. I didn't had to the time to learn how to use the developer interface of firefox so the debugger is still a luxury to me.

Comment: I found the issue while answering ! Your answers was very useful, thank you.
I was trying to reach msg[i] with i starting at 1. But looking at the structure of msg, I realized that all the info I added was inside msg[0] no need to iterate that part ! That solved everything. Thank you very much.